# Key combinations with 'j' like "rj" doesn't work correctly on VSCode Vim

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Vim for VSCode on macOS.
When I type "rj" to replace a character under the cursor to 'j', it doesn't work and my cursor moves down.
Key combinations with 'j' or 'k' like "rj", "fj", "rk", etc., doesn't work correctly  but with 'h' or 'l', there is no problem.

I'm using latest version of VSCode and Vim for VSCode.
I tried deleting everything on settings.json, but nothing has changed.
I also tried the same thing on vim from terminal.app, it works as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause by myself.
I don't know why, but the wrong key bindings had been set.
I removed the following lines from Keybindings.json, and the problem was solved.

```
{
    "key": "k",
    "command": "cursorUp",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl && vim.mode == 'Normal' && !suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "j",
    "command": "cursorDown",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && !inDebugRepl && vim.mode == 'Normal' && !suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  }
```